# Trouble installing color picker

Tags: jquery, html, css

I found this [project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/452401/ColorPicker-a-jQuery-UI-Widget) and I'm not sure why it's not working in my application. I'm sure it's something simple I just can't figure out what...

Errors:
TypeError: e.widget is not a function evol.colorpicker.min.js:10
TypeError: $(...).colorpicker is not a function

I have 
JQuery 2.1.1
JQuery UI 1.11.1

**JQuery**

```
@section Scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Custom/custom.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Custom/evol.colorpicker.min.js")
}
```

**Custom.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mycolor").colorpicker();
});
```

**CSS**

```
@section Styles
{
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/evol.colorpicker.css")
}
```

**Html**

```
<div style="width:128px">
   <input style="width:100px;" id="mycolor" class="colorPicker evo-cp0" />
   <div class="evo-colorind" style="background-color:#8db3e2"></div>
</div>
```

**Bundles**

```
     bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
    }
}
```

**EDIT SCRIPT LOCATION**

```
@section Scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Custom/custom.js")"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript"  src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Custom/evol.colorpicker.min.js")" ></script>
}
```

Comment: Good call the errors are now in the question... I'll look into them

Comment: Show scripts which in bundles

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: If there are many pickers that are available, try to change this `$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mycolor").colorpicker();
});` to another `colorpicker` that has some arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You should place scripts in bundlr

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Custom/custom.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Custom/evol.colorpicker.min.js")
```

This is not name of bundles.I suppose these only script name.But you using their as bundle name

Try

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Custom/custom.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Custom/evol.colorpicker.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but in future put these scripts to bundle

Comment: I added the scripts with the script tags to `@section Scripts` and I'm unfortunately still getting the same two errors

Comment: CHeck correct path to scripts.Does evol.colorpicker.min.js exactly place in custom folder.By logic custom folder for your scripts

Comment: Copy code from evol.colorpicker.min.js and paste on your page between tags scripts <script>put here</script> for testing

Comment: K I did, same error it looks like I'll have to contact the developer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60733/discussion-between-joetinger-and-cosset).

Comment: I needed to add `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")` so after I added that it worked. Thanks for the help and the great tips on bundles